# How to add outline to QGraphicsLineItem?

Tags: qt, c++11

I want to have a QGraphicsLineItem where it is outlined by a certain color.

I have tried using

```
QGraphicsLineItem::setColor(QColor(...))
```

However this only paints the inside.

What function must I call to create an outline?

Being more specific, let's say this is a normal QGraphicsLineItem

```
--------------------------------------
    10px
    green QGraphicsLineItem
--------------------------------------
```

What I want is a completely different (solid) color outside of the boundaries, like so,

```
--------------------------------------
2px blue 
--------------------------------------
10px
green
--------------------------------------
2px blue
--------------------------------------
```

So a drop shadow effect won't work, hopefully this is clear.

Comment: You could illustrate what you want with an image.

Comment: ...plus you could take a look at [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html).

Comment: @eyllanesc - I've added an image that hopefully makes it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 2

Another way to add an outline is to use [QPainter::strokePath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#strokePath). For that you have to subclass *QGraphicsLineItem* and reimplement the `paint` method.

**Note:** This approach is more complex, as it requires subclassing, but it allows more freedom, including setting the ticknes and the color of the outline.

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
void OutLineItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QPainterPath outline;

    outline.moveTo(line().p1());
    outline.lineTo(line().p2());

    painter->save();
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter->strokePath(outline, QPen(m_outlineColor, 2*m_outlineWidth + pen().width()));
    painter->setPen(pen());
    painter->drawLine(line());
    painter->restore();
}
```

The full code of the example I have prepared for you is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/scopchanov/SO-OutLine).

This example produces the following result:

[image: Window with a thick green line with a solid blue outline]

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

One way to add an outline to `QGraphicsLineItem` is to use [QGraphicsDropShadowEffect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html) with zero offset.

**Note:** This approach does not require subclassing, but it is not so robust, as it does not allow the tickness to be set precisely and the outline is not solid. However, in some cases this might work just fine.

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    auto *item = new QGraphicsLineItem(50, 50, 250, 150);
    auto *effect = new QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(this);

    effect->setColor(Qt::blue);
    effect->setOffset(0);
    effect->setBlurRadius(10);

    item->setPen(QPen(Qt::green, 10));
    item->setGraphicsEffect(effect);

    view->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
    view->scene()->addItem(item);

    setCentralWidget(view);
    resize(300, 200);
}
```

This example produces the following result:

[image: Window with a thick green line with a glowing blue outline]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that's not quite what I'm looking for, I will clarify in post.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @qtquestionstack, is it OK now? Tell me if you want this to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

You can addpath on QGraphicsscene,Make sure that the coordinates of the point are in the scene coordinate system

```
void Myclass::DrawOutline()
{
    int cntLeft = ptLeft.count();
    int cntRight = ptRight.count();
    if (cntLeft && cntRight)
    {
        QPainterPath polygonPath;
        QVector <QPoint> points;

        for (int i = 0;i < cntLeft;i++)
        {
            QPoint pos;
            points.push_back(pos);
        }

        for (int i = cntRight-1;i >=0;i--)
        {
            QPoint pos;
            points.push_back(pos);
        }
        polygonPath.addPolygon(QPolygon(points));
        polygonPath.closeSubpath();
        QPen pen;
        pen.setColor(QColor(0,0,0));
        pen.setWidth(1);
        m_scene->addPath(polygonPath, pen);
    }
}
```